# Как использовать 2 диска Linux?

Tags: linux, hdd, fedora, разметка-диска

Я хочу попробовать перейти с Виндовс на Linux Fedora.  У меня на ноутбуке 2 диска, один SSD на 120гб, другой HDD на 1тб, и мне нужно чтоб на SSD была сама Linux, а на HDD например какое-то ПО, игры и т.д.
В Linux'е я новичек, и раньше использовал только один диск, SSD, но места не хватало и приходилось переходить на Винду.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Можно сделать как я это сделал - примонтировал большой диск в /opt/disk. Там создал каталог для фильмов и для фоток и симлинками в домашний каталог. И все красиво.

Comment: так и делайте, на sdd устанавливайте систему, а после hdd подмонтируйте в удобное для вас место.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Установи Linux на ssd, отформатируй второй диск как нравится и он уже готов под использование и находится в "Другие места" файлового менеджера.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но нужно по нему кликнуть чтоб подключить. Для подключения автоматически в утилите Disks в параметрах монтирования поставь галку и каталог куда его подключать - точку монтирования.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо. Думал это делается как-то сложнее.